# Erlang: Recursion vs Lists

Tags: list, recursion, erlang

I'm newbie in Erlang and i'm trying to understand why recursion working faster than using list (that can even got an error "can't allocate memory in heap").

I created two functions to find primes for a value (pretty straight forward):

1. using recursion:

   ```
   find_factor_rec(List, Max, _, NextValue)
       when NextValue > Max ->
           List;

   find_factor_rec(List, Max, Value, NextValue)->
       if (Value rem NextValue =:= 0) ->
           find_factor_rec([NextValue|List], Max, Value, NextValue + 1);
       true ->
           find_factor_rec(List, Max, Value, NextValue + 1)
       end
   .

   find_factors(Val)->
       find_factor_rec([], round(math:sqrt(Val)) + 1, Val, 2).
   ```
2. list

   ```
   find_factors1(Val) ->
       [X || X <- lists:seq(2, round(math:sqrt(Val)) + 1), Val rem X =:= 0].
   ```

while i'm passing small values - both are at the same time. When i'm passing huge values like 403851455234578 the second function became slower and slower and even throws error.

Could someone please explain why first function better than list? 
Are there better way to rewrite function?
Are there any name convention for the first listing? (function plus their "child-recursive-functions")

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first function is faster because you only calculate the top number once. In the second function, you create all the numbers from 2 to the square root plus one. That's 20096056 integers in a list.

```
lists:seq(2, round(math:sqrt(Val)) % Creates a list from 2 to 20096056
```

Your problem doesn't suit itself to a solution that creates the whole search space in memory, because of space and performance reasons.

To conclude, the use of lists here is very sub-optimal.

---

As for naming conventions: when the function has a different arity (a different number of arguments) one usually names it the same. Erlang does not see it as the same function though, only functions with the same name and arity are considered equal.

```
find_factors(Val)-> find_factor_rec([], round(math:sqrt(Val)) + 1, Val, 2).

find_factors(List, Max, _, NextValue) when NextValue > Max ->
    List;
find_factors(List, Max, Value, NextValue) ->
    if 
        (Value rem NextValue =:= 0) ->
            find_factors([NextValue|List], Max, Value, NextValue + 1);
        true ->
            find_factors(List, Max, Value, NextValue + 1)
    end.
```

Comment: Adam, thanks for you answer

You wrote:
> The first function is faster because you only calculate the top number
> once. In the second function, you create all the numbers from 2 to the
> square root plus one.

In other words it means that the following construction:

> [X || X <- lists:seq(2, round(math:sqrt(Val)) + 1), Val rem X =:=0]

works in the following way:

 - create list starting from 2 to sqrt(Val) + 1
 - apply condition (filtering out value if it is not factor).

Is it true?

I suppose that list work in the other way:

 - get next value from sequence
 - apply condition.
 - repeat

Comment: Erlang is not lazy so the whole list is first created and then you pass over it applying the condition. It is because you create the whole list that you can run out of memory. The difference speed is also from first creating the list.